# Simple tab activity in android

Tags: java, android, android-tabhost, android-tabactivity

**What i am trying to do**::

[image]

**BreakfastLunchDinnerIndividualListOfItems.java**

```
public class BreakfastLunchDinnerIndividualListOfItems extends TabActivity implements OnTabChangeListener{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.breakfast_lunch_dinner_individual_list_of_items);

        Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); // The activity TabHost
        TabHost.TabSpec spec; // Reusable TabSpec for each tab
        Intent intent; // Reusable Intent for each tab

        String REST = getTabHost().toString();

        // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Starters.class);
        //intent.putExtra("Starters", REST);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Starters").setIndicator("Starters").setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        // Do the same for the other tabs

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, BLD_IndividualListOfItems_MainCourse.class);
        //intent.putExtra("MainCourse", REST);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("MAIN_COURSE").setIndicator("Main Course").setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
    }

    public void onTabChanged(String arg0)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),arg0, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

---

- I tried with `String REST = getTabHost().toString();` problem is that
  on click of tab i am not able to send perticular `tabtext` to the
  activity that the tab launches
- I know tab activity is depricated, i am just learning
- How to resolve this, hope i am clear

Comment: `TabActivity` is deprecated. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html

Comment: I know tab activity is depricated .... but i am just trying to learn some basics .... how can we achieve this !

Comment: i would suggest you to use fragments as suggested in the docs and as i suggested previously to your other posts use interface as a callback to the activity. from activity communicate value to other fragment

Comment: But why would you want to start with deprecated thing? Instead as @Raghunandan has suggested, start with fragment, at least basics of it would help you out.

Comment: developer basics: never use deprecated codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Starters").setIndicator("Starters").setContent(intent);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("MAIN_COURSE").setIndicator("Main Course").setContent(intent);
```

here `Starters` and `Main Course` are the titles of tabs. The easiest way to send this strings to bounded activities is to send them throught intents which are bounded to corresponding
tabSpecs.

```
    String TAB_TITLE="Starters";
    Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Starters.class);

    Bundle bundle =new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("key_title", TAB_TITLE);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);

    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Starters").setIndicator(TAB_TITLE).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

And here is how you can get this string in `BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Starters` activity :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     ...
     String title=getIntent().getExtras().getString("key_title");
}
```

But as Raghunandan says, it's better to use fragments instead of depracated `TabActivity`.

EDITED:

if you want to send text to corresponding activity dinamically, i mean exactly after tab is changed - you can:

1. create and broadcast custom intent with your string. [(CUSTOM_INTENT_EXAMPLE)](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/02/02/custom-intents-and-broadcasting-with-receivers/)
2. in `BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Starters` activity register `BroadcastReciever` which will catch your custom intent and take text from it. [(BROADCAST_RECIEVER_FROM_ACTIVITY_EXAMPLE)](http://inchoo.net/mobile-development/android-development/broadcast-receiver-from-activity/)

You can't directly access tab text from `BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Starters`, because `TabActivity` and `BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Starters` are two different activities. 
But you can send data between activities via bundles, static fields, singletons etc. Here is link to docs
http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/framework.html#3

Comment: @ almaz_from_kazan ..... Thank you .... i did achieve my goal .... i have one more doubt .... you have hardcoded the String TAB_TITLE="Starters" ...... is there a way i can dynamically access the tab text ... so i could pass .... i am refering similarly to how we dynamically fetch values from edittext .... any inputs ?